# Finding dates in window forms using DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am writing a windows form application ask the user for a date and find the day of that date for the next 8 years.

What I have so far is current date and the date the user has entered.

I am confused on how to get the days for the next 8 years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.AddYears(x)` where "x" is the amount of years that needs to be added

For example:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 10, 30);

Console.WriteLine("On {0} in 2017", date.AddYears(1).DayOfWeek);    
Console.WriteLine("On {0} in 2018", date.AddYears(2).DayOfWeek);
Console.WriteLine("On {0} in 2019", date.AddYears(3).DayOfWeek);
Console.WriteLine("On {0} in 2020", date.AddYears(4).DayOfWeek);
Console.WriteLine("On {0} in 2021", date.AddYears(5).DayOfWeek);
```

or

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 10, 30);

int amount = 8; //amount of years
for (int i = 1; i < amount + 1; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("On {0} in {1}", date.AddYears(i).DayOfWeek, date.AddYears(i).Year);
}
```

Live ideone example: https://ideone.com/kigfVA

Comment: Thanks for the help